# How to set a default value for an optional positional parameter of type Function?

Tags: dart

I am passing a Function as an optional parameter to the constructor but I can't assign a default value.

```
void main() {
  Person p = Person();
  print(p.foo('Hello'));
}

class Person {
  final String Function(String) foo;
  Person({this.foo});
}
```

now trying to assign a default value: `Person({this.foo = (val) {return val;});` 
produces the error: `Error: Not a constant expression.` I am aware the parameter must be `const` but using `const` or even `static` infront of `(val) {return val;}` does not work.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use *constant values* (aka. compile-time constants) as default values.
You cannot create a constant function literal, so there is no way to write the function in-line in the constructor.

However, references to top-level or static functions are constants, so you can declare the default value function as a static function or top-level function.

```dart
void main() {
  Person p = Person();
  print(p.foo('Hello')); // Prints "Hello"
}

class Person {
  final String Function(String) foo;
  Person({this.foo = _identity});
  static String _identity(String value) => value;
}
// or as top-level.
// String _identity(String value) => value;
```

You can (and should) choose to make the function public if the default value is on an *instance method*, and you expect anyone to extend or implement your class. In that case, they need to declare the same default value.

Another option, which is often at least as useful, is to not use a default value, but replace a `null` before using the value:

```dart
class Person {
  final String Function(String) foo;
  Person({String Function(String) foo}) : foo = foo ?? _identity;
  static String _identity(String value) => value;
}
```

or even using a non-constant value:

```
class Person {
  final String Function(String) foo;
  Person({String Function(String) foo}) : foo = (foo ?? (String x) => x);
}
```

For a constructor, it makes very little difference. If it was an instance method instead, using `??` to replace `null` avoids subclasses having to use the exact same function as default value.

Personally I recommend always using `??` instead of a default value. It's more flexible since it allows non-constant values. For non-function default values, you'll have to document the default behavior instead of just letting the dartDoc show `{int x = 42}`, but for functions, you'll have to document them anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```dart
void main() {
  Person pLower = Person(foo: (a) => a.toLowerCase());
  print(pLower.foo('Hello'));
  Person pDefault = Person();
  print(pDefault.foo('Hello'));
}

class Person {
  static String defaultFoo(String a) => a.toUpperCase();
  final String Function(String) foo;
  Person({this.foo = defaultFoo});
}
```

**Output**

```
hello
HELLO
```